# How to call a function when a Widget comes into view (not created)?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, routes, navigation

I need to refresh the state of a widget when it comes into view. For example, when I call `Navigator.push(SomePage());` and then press the back button, the earlier page is not created, as it is still in the tree, so `initState()` does not work.

Basically I need to refresh the state of a page when it is seen after pressing back button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Navigator.push` returns a `Future` that completes with the value that is passed to the `pop` method when the pushed route is popped.

Therefore, you can `await` or use `.then` to complete an action following the `pop`.

```dart
await Navigator.push(SomePage());
//Do some action
```

or

```dart
Navigator.push(SomePage()).then((_){
  //Do some action
});
```